# Android Linear layout

Tags: android-linearlayout

```
 <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

In linearlayout, view will be added from top to bottom, Can we override and make it add view from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can not, what you can do is change the layout and use a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot override linear layout in the way you wish to do.You can use relative layout for that.
You can check that there is no option available to do that in a linear layout,I have tried that.

Comment: :How can I add view from bottom to top in relative layout ?

Answer (score 0):

is too easy, just drag the items you use and arrange them any way you want, do not restrict in any way what the RelativeLayout